# Redirect jquery ui dialog on close

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, dialog

I tried different ways to do this but i cant get it work. this is the code:

```
    $.ui.dialog.defaults.bgiframe = true;
$(function() {
    $("#category_edit_dialog").dialog({
        width: 960,
        hide: 'slide',
        position: 'top',
        show: 'slide',
        close: function(event, ui) { redirect here? how? }
    });
    });
});
```

Thanks dekomote for helping me. At his advice i solved the problem: here is the full working code:

```
 $.ui.dialog.defaults.bgiframe = true;
$(function() {
    $("#category_edit_dialog").dialog({
        width: 960,
        hide: 'slide',
        position: 'top',
        show: 'slide',
        close: function(event, ui) { location.href = 'url here' }
    });
});
```

Comment: did you try  location.href = 'where you want to redirect'

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
    $.ui.dialog.defaults.bgiframe = true;
    $(function() {
        $("#category_edit_dialog").dialog({
            width: 960,
            hide: 'slide',
            position: 'top',
            show: 'slide',
            close: function(event, ui) { window.location.href = "page.html"; }
        });
        });
    });
```

**where "page.html" is the page you wish to redirect to on close**

Comment: i already got it work thanks to dekomote but your code works as well :) thanks!